# function in class that multiplies 2 hidden variables

Tags: c++

> Create a class with two variables as data members and create a member
>   function to multiply it?

```
 class Madina{
  int n1,n2 ;

 public:int getN1(){
   return n1 ;
 }
 public:int getN2(){
   return n2 ;
 }
 public:int setN1(int new_n1){
   n1 = new_n1 ;
 }
 public:int setN2(int new_n2){
   n2 = new_n2 ;
 }
public:int func(){
  return n1*n2;
}

};


int main(){

  Madina example ;
  int n1 =0;
  int n2 =0;
  cout << "Input"<<endl ;
  cout << "Enter 1st number"<<endl;
  cin >> n1 ;
  cout << "Enter 2nd number"<<endl ;
  cin >> n2 ;

  example.setN1(n1);
  example.setN2(n2);

  cout << "get n1 " << example.getN1()<<endl;
  cout << "get n2 " << example.getN2()<<endl;

  cout << "Output product is "<< example.func()<<endl ;
  return 0 ;


}
```

I dont' know why the program just crashes.. without explaining anything!

Comment: When you are writing c++ you needn't declare each method public explicitly.

Comment: Your program doesn't crash for me either. But there's an obvious problem of using `cin` without any kind of error checking.

Comment: Your program isn't crashing on mine either, it gives a perfect result. Which compiler are you using ?

Comment: In case it isn't clear from the answer: you have *undefined behaviour* because you're not returning anything from functions with a non-void return type.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I know it's undefined behaviour, but the irony is that I got the correct answer for all the cases I tried with it ( except decimals as the variables are not float )..

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly changed your code.

Why were your setter methods returning ints? Setter methods should never return anything? I have tested this code and it works fine for me.

Also as mentioned above, methods only need to be declared public once not individually.

```
#include <iostream>

class Madina {
    int n1,n2 ;

    public:
    int getN1() {
        return n1 ;
    }
    int getN2() {
        return n2 ;
    }
    void setN1(int new_n1) {
        n1 = new_n1 ;
    }
    void setN2(int new_n2) {
        n2 = new_n2 ;
    }
    int func() {
        return n1*n2;
    }
};

using namespace std;
int main() {
    Madina example;
    int n1 =0;
    int n2 =0;
    cout << "Input"<<endl;
    cout << "Enter 1st number"<<endl;
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "Enter 2nd number"<<endl;
    cin >> n2;

    example.setN1(n1);
    example.setN2(n2);

    cout << "get n1 " << example.getN1()<<endl;
    cout << "get n2 " << example.getN2()<<endl;

    cout << "Output product is "<< example.func()<<endl ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Also, should have C++ tag not Java tag as mentioned by other users.

Comment: Good catch. Not returning from the setters would be undefined behaviour.